# Cryptic issue: RequestMappingHandlerAdapter: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I am running into a cryptic issue with the spring-mvc-test and the **following test class**:

```
import static com.mycompany.testUtils.SecurityRequestPostProcessors.userDetailsService;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.mycompany.services.AccountService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:spring-config-*.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml" })
public class SecurityTests {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/welcome").with(userDetailsService("dummy@mycompany.com")))
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class testConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public AccountService accountService() {
            return mock(AccountService.class);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- <context:annotation-config/> -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />


    <!-- Internationalization -->
    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="fr" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

Here is the **stacktrace** at last:

```
10:51:35.639 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@fb76c8] to prepare test instance [com.mycompany.ui.controller.security.SecurityTests@1337d64]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:128) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1000) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.put(Charset.java:550) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.access$300(Charset.java:276) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset$4.run(Charset.java:593) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset$4.run(Charset.java:585) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets(Charset.java:584) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.<init>(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:66) ~[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.<init>(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:56) ~[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
10:51:35.651 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [[TestContext@165e583 testClass = SecurityTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1e6cb2a testClass = SecurityTests, locations = '{classpath*:spring-config-*.xml, file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]], dirtiesContext [false].
```

Note that the app runs fine from a browser. The problem occurs **only when the above test class is run**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much researching, I pinpointed the problem to one of our maven dependencies, i.e. our Sybase JDBC driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
    <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
    <version>7.07.GA</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Therefore, this has got nothing to do with spring of the jdk.